# How to group data by each element of nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have nested arrays, and need group data by each of element of "foo.foo_id" array and calculate number of occurrences fro each of element (1,2,3,.. 33,34...n).

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("51818aabfa746a8e3e000000"),
  "foo": {
    "foo_id": [
      31,
      72,
      533,
      23332,
      233434
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$foo.foo_id"
}, {$group: {
    _id: "$foo.foo_id",
    count: {$sum: 1}
}})
```

Comment: This works. Thx. 
About 22 sec for 6M of documents, on Intel® Core™ i7-920 Quad-Core, 24GB RAM. Fine :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can try with map/reduce, but I don't know if it would be faster.

Comment: map/reduce would be significantly slower.  maybe 5x to 10x slower.